# Is eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0 removed from npm? It is not getting installed

Tags: node.js, server, devops, npm-install

While installing packages using npm on server, I am getting 404 error related to this module, `eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0`. Can anyone help me resolve this?

I tried to install it separately too, but still got errors related to 404.
Here's the logs:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"2.x - 6.x" from eslint-plugin-import@2.18.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-import@"2.18.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.14.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!       dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@5.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: Please show the error message, because it's clearly there https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-base/v/13.1.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Konrad Sir I have edited the question, and provided the entire logs.

Comment: The error says that you are using `eslint@6.0.1`, but the other modules want  `eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" `

Comment: @Konrad Sir changes I need to do this fix? shall I change it in package.json and try reinstallation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a peer dependency issue usually occurs in npm version => 7, hence we have to use a flag, and install, the command goes like

`npm i --leagcy-peer-deps`